# .sh not running and getting no errors

Tags: bash, scripts, .sh

I am try to create a .sh file to check to see if the server is running and if not to start it. i am not getting any echo's from this script or any fails but it is not running. can some one help me fix this or a better way to right it. i am not a programmer i just edited a few others scripts to get this.

```bash
JAVA="java -Xms512M -Xmx3072M -XX:PermSize=128m -jar FTBServer.jar nogui"
DIR="/home/jon/FTB/FTBnew"

if [ "$1" = start ] ; then
    if ps -ef | grep FTBServer.jar | grep -v -q grep ; then
        echo "Minecraft is already running"
    else
        echo "Starting!" && cd $DIR && screen -dmS minecraft $JAVA
        sleep 7
        if ps -ef | grep minecraft_server.jar | grep -v -q grep ; then
            echo "Minecraft server started successfully"
        else
            echo "Minecraft server failed to start"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

this is what i get and when i run it

```
root@FTB:/home/jon/FTB/FTBnew# bash Check.sh
root@FTB:/home/jon/FTB/FTBnew#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you logic is inside an `if [ "$1" = start ]` block, so if you don't give that argument on the command line, your script doesn't do anything.

You should validate the arguments first:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ "$1" != "start" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 start"
    exit 1
else 
    # your stuff here
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment after i removed the hole thing in general     if [ "$1" = start ]     it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it as

```
bash Check.sh start
```

... because nothing is done if `[ "$1" != start ]`.

Also, this line

```
if ps -ef | grep minecraft_server.jar | grep -v -q grep ; then
```

should be

```
if ps -ef | grep FTBServer.jar | grep -v -q grep ; then
```

---

Some other notes:

- Use arrays for Bash arguments.
- Quote variables when they are used.
- Use `[[` instead of `[`.
- `if` line correction as shown above.

So, a more correct version would be:

```
JAVA=(java -Xms512M -Xmx3072M -XX:PermSize=128m -jar FTBServer.jar nogui)
DIR="/home/jon/FTB/FTBnew"

if [[ "$1" == start ]]; then
    if ps -ef | grep FTBServer.jar | grep -v -q grep; then
        echo "Minecraft is already running"
    else
        echo "Starting!"
        cd "$DIR" &&
        screen -dmS minecraft "${JAVA[@]}"
        sleep 7
        if ps -ef | grep FTBServer.jar | grep -v -q grep; then
            echo "Minecraft server started successfully"
        else
            echo "Minecraft server failed to start"
        fi
    fi
fi
```